# Python-JSON - How to parse API output?

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new.

I wrote this python script to make an API call from blockr.io to check the balance of multiple bitcoin addresses.

The contents of btcaddy.txt are bitcoin addresses seperated by commas. For this example, let it parse [this](http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/info/1FQCJjV3JwoQVgRYVRmDUFyZD9rt946Yp9,1BitmixerEiyyp3eTLaCpgBbhYERs48qza,1CyDUaBBhZAwGZEnL266Kb4tRQ1Br9Rj8c).

```
import urllib2
import json


btcaddy = open("btcaddy.txt","r")


urlRequest = urllib2.Request("http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/info/" + btcaddy.read())
data = urllib2.urlopen(urlRequest).read()
json_data = json.loads(data)

balance = float(json_data['data''address'])
print balance

raw_input()
```

However, it gives me an error. What am I doing wrong? For now, how do I get it to print the balance of the addresses?

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: missing comma & brackets after `'data' 'address'`? are you sure data has its content in a json format? It wouldn't hurt if you add the error you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done multiple things wrong in your code. Here's my fix. I recommend a for loop.

```
import json
import urllib

addresses = open("btcaddy.txt", "r").read()

base_url = "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/info/"
request = urllib.urlopen(base_url+addresses)
result = json.loads(request.read())['data']
for balance in result:
    print balance['address'], ":" , balance['balance'], "BTC"
```

You don't need an input at the end, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is clear, but your tries not.

You said, you have a file, with at least, more than registry. So you need to retrieve the lines of this file.

```
with open("btcaddy.txt","r") as a:
    addresses = a.readlines()
```

Now you could iterate over registries and make a request to this uri. The `urllib` module is enough for this task.

```
import json
import urllib

base_url = "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/info/%s"

for address in addresses:
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url % address)
    result = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf8'))
    print(result)
```

HTTP sends bytes as response, so you should to us `decode('utf8')` as approach to handle with data.

Comment: When I try your code, I get 
(AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request')

Comment: Probably should just be: `request = urllib.urlopen()`

Comment: If you are using Python 2, you should use @zachyee's aproach.